# How can I recover the password of a TrueCrypt vlume?

Tags: passwords, truecrypt, passphrase

I am trying to recover the password of a trucrypt volume.
It is composed by a combination of 4 words (one invented). I remember 3 of them but not their order.
Do you know any tools that cold help me recover the volume? The most useful feature would be the possibility of creating /saving probable passwords by recombining the known items and applying minor modifications

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Brute Forcing Password to a Truecrypt-encrypted file with Partial Knowledge](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/30605/6939)